module 'openai' has no attribute 'OpenAI'
I installed the latest openai version:
pip install openai==1.23.6

then
from openai import OpenAI

I get error

cannot import name 'OpenAI' from 'openai'

From https://pypi.org/project/openai/ openai version 1.23.6 example
import os
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Say this is a test",
        }
    ],
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
)


 print(openai.__file__) refers to: /home/yilmaz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/__init__.py

print(dir(openai))
['APIError', 'Audio', 'Callable', 'ChatCompletion', 'Completion', 'ContextVar', 'Customer', 'Deployment', 'Edit', 'Embedding', 'Engine', 'ErrorObject', 'File', 'FineTune', 'FineTuningJob', 'Image', 'InvalidRequestError', 'Model', 'Moderation', 'OpenAIError', 'Optional', 'TYPE_CHECKING', 'Union', 'VERSION', '__all__', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'aiosession', 'api_base', 'api_key', 'api_key_path', 'api_requestor', 'api_resources', 'api_type', 'api_version', 'app_info', 'ca_bundle_path', 'datalib', 'debug', 'enable_telemetry', 'error', 'log', 'openai_object', 'openai_response', 'organization', 'os', 'proxy', 'requestssession', 'sys', 'util', 'verify_ssl_certs', 'version']

pip show openai shows correct version: "Version: 1.23.6"



Is your python script itself named openai.py?

no. Untitled.ipybn

Check what import openai; print(openai.__file__) refers to. It's clearly something other than what your pip command was instructed to download.

Do you have some other file named openai.py?

@CharlesDuffy it referst to /home/yilmaz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/__init__.py i think that is the correct

Well, that's odd.  Can you show the output of import openai; print(dir(openai))

And in the same interpreter session where that was your print output openai.OpenAI still isn't found? Don't test one thing in IPython and a separate thing at the command line -- make sure you test them both the same way.

@JohnGordon i did but it does not show OpenAI. but even official package example shows that it should have

openai.OpenAI is an alias -- the real client is imported from a distinct, private location (openai._client.OpenAI). Obviously, though, since it's marked private you shouldn't use it directly.

That said, you can see that in the real file OpenAI is in __all__ -- at https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/e9724398d2bdd87ba41f199c3577303f1b80f2c7/src/openai/init.py#L64

Does openai.__version__ match up with the version number pip gave you? (If it doesn't, we want to look at where pip is installing things and compare that location to your actual sys.path).

@CharlesDuffy no :(  it gives 0.27.9. how is this possible?.  i specified in pip install and pip show shows correct version.

Like I said, "need to look at where pip is installing things and compare that to your sys.path".

First, how are you running pip? If you're just using pip install, stop that and use python -m pip install instead to make sure you're using the copy of pip for the same interpreter that's first in your PATH as python. Similarly, use python -m pip show, not pip show on its own.

Second, compare the output from the shell commands type pip and type python -- if one is coming from a virtualenv and the other isn't, or one is defined with an alias and the other isn't, or so forth... well, there you are.

@CharlesDuffy pip installs it to python3.11 site_packages direcyory which is correct. when i run python --version is shows 3.11. everything seems correct

There's not just one site-packages directory -- there's the systemwide one, used when you run as sudo, the per-user one, an additional per-virtualenv one if you use virtualenvs (which you should), etc etc etc. So there's also not just one place for pip list to show.

...indeed, part of the point of using virtualenvs (with the modern default of --system-site-packages being turned off) is so you can avoid this kind of mess and have just one place all your libraries come from (for each given project/purpose), rather than having them merged from several different sources.

(some of us go further and use NixOS, which does that kind of management but for everything, not just Python modules -- you can have project X built against a different libc or zlib or openssl than project Y and they don't get in each others' way).

This could possibly be helpful moving forward: https://gist.github.com/ParityError/f5bd68c4571b1358daa63db05fabfb32

@CharlesDuffy how come print(openai.__file__) refers to correct python3.11 site_packages. when I run pip show openai it also refers to correct python3.11 site_packages.  python --version prints correct python 3.11. i still cannot understand why this is happening.

@CharlesDuffy creating a new env solved the issue. can you pls write an answer and I will accept

I'd need a [MRE] -- steps that when followed let me cause the same problem in an environment I can inspect -- to dig into the "why". Otherwise, I'm not sure this is sufficiently distinct from the hundreds of other questions already in our knowledgebase about situations where pip's view of reality and actual sys.path contents diverge.

Like @CharlesDuffy has mentioned, it seems like your pip command doesn't work with /home/yilmaz/.local/lib/python3.11/ at all, so openai 0.27.9 remains outdated. Probably pip points to another python installation (not 3.11, or even to python2).

You can run your actual python derectly (e.g. python 3.11) to call pip by typing python3.11 -m pip instead of just pip . This method is good for installing every-day-use applications, but not for the development
You can create fresh venv for your project and install all the modules there by python3.11 -m venv your_project and then source your_project/bin/activate .
You can use high-level tools to create and manage virtual environments, like virtulalenv or pipenv


I activated my environment then installed openai using conda
conda install conda-forge::openai

from openai import OpenAI

client=OpenAI(api_key=key)

 response = client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt-4o-mini",    messages=[{"role":"user","content":instructions}])
    stock_symbol=response.choices[0].message.content


You can try
import openai

Then
client = openai.OpenAI()
chat = client.chat....

rest is same

Have you ever had a problem importing where this was the fix?  It makes no sense to me that python would have trouble importing a class directly, but would allow you to reference the same class through its parent path.
